# Azure ML: What means reconnecting terminal?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-python-sdk

I am a newbie in this, and I am facing some problems with the Azure ML workspace. I ran a python code from the terminal, and then I opened another terminal to check the process. I got the following message in the terminal that checked the process:

[image]

What does this mean? It keeps running, but I don't know if it is a bad message. It takes soo long, and I don't want to lose the processing time.

I appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this mean? It keeps running, but I don't know if it is a bad message. It takes soo long, and I don't want to lose the processing time.

- `Reconnecting terminal` message can appear for multiple reasons like intermittent connectivity issues, unused active terminal sessions, processing of different size/format of data.
- Make sure you close any unused terminal sessions to preserve your compute instance's resources. Idle terminals may impact the performance of compute instances.

You can refer to [Access a compute instance terminal in your workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-terminal#manage-terminal-sessions), [Optimize data processing with Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-optimize-data-processing) and [Azure ML: Speed up processing time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiScfw9i4FM)

Comment: Tkx for your answer and tips.